# python multithreading comunication throught mailbox

Tags: python, multithreading, ipc, python-multithreading

I want to make an applications with 10 threads which communicate between them 2 by 2 by a mailbox. One thread writes a message in a file, the other one reads it. Desired output:

```
Thread  1 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  2 : Q
Thread  3 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  4 : Q
Thread  5 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  6 : Q
Thread  7 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  8 : Q
Thread  9 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  10 : Q
```

But it do not works. ERROR:

```
TypeError: read() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

What can I do to slove my problem? My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import threading
import time    


def write(message, i):
    print "Thread  %d writes message: %s to file:  %s !" % (i, 'Q', 'testfile.txt')     
    file = open("testfile.txt","w")
    file.write(message)
    file.close()
    return


def read(i):
    with open("testfile.txt", 'r') as fin:
            msg = fin.read()
    print "Thread  %d : %s \n" % (i, msg)
    return


while 1:
    for i in range(5):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=write, args=("Q", int(2*i-1)))
        t1.start()

        time.sleep(0.2)

        t2 = threading.Thread(target=read, args=(int(2*i)))
        t2.start()

        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed two things inside while loop:

1) If you want first thread to be `Thread 1`, 2i+1 and 2i+2 should be passed

2) If you want to pass parameters to a function, you should pass iterable data type. Simply, put a comma after `int(2*i+2)`.

```
while 1:
    for i in range(5):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=write, args=("Q", int(2*i+1)))
        t1.start()
        t1.join()
        time.sleep(0.5)

        t2 = threading.Thread(target=read, args=(int(2*i+2),))
        t2.start()
        t2.join()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Output:

```
Thread  1 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  2 : Q

Thread  3 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  4 : Q

Thread  5 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  6 : Q

Thread  7 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  8 : Q

Thread  9 writes message: Q to file:  testfile.txt !
Thread  10 : Q
```